# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error every time I tried to map over an ingredients array

here is the ingredients array

```
ingredients": [
  "2 jalapeno peppers, cut in half lengthwise and seeded",
  "2 slices sour dough bread",
  "1 tablespoon butter, room temperature",
  "2 tablespoons cream cheese, room temperature",
  "1/2 cup jack and cheddar cheese, shredded",
  "1 tablespoon tortilla chips, crumbled\n"
],
```

and here is my code

```
renderRecipe(){
    const {recipe}= this.props;
    const recipeTitle = recipe.title;
    const publisher = recipe.publisher;
    const ingredients = recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
        console.log(ingredient);
        return <li key={recipeId}> {ingredient} </li>     
    })

    const recipeId = recipe.recipe_id;
    const recipeImage = recipe.image_url;

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{recipeId}</p>
            <img src={recipeImage} />

           <ul>
               {ingredients}
           </ul>


        </div>
    )

}render() {

return (
  <div>
      {this.renderRecipe()}

  </div>
)}}const mapStateToProps= state => ({
recipe: state.recipe.recipe})export default connect (mapStateToProps)(Recipe)
```

and I get this error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined)
and without the map, the app works fine

please help,
thanks, guys

Comment: It entirely possible that ingredients is not available initially in recipe object. Could you try and add a conditional render there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably in the first render you dont have your recipe.ingredients filled yet. React properties arrive sometimes later and couple of render runs before the prop filled.

Make and additional check to make sure you have the required data. If not you can alway return null or display just a loading span. Do this before mapping through the ingredients.

```
if (!this.props.recipe || !this.props.recipe.ingredients || this.props.recipe.ingredients.length === 0) {
    return null;
}
```

You can also use proptypes.defaultProps to avoid checks like that.

In a long term solution I also recommend to create a separate util file, which has a function like this:

```
export function getVariable(contentObj, name, defaultReturn) {
    const nameChain = name.split('.');
    const resultVariable = nameChain.reduce((levelResultObj, nameElement) => {
        return levelResultObj && levelResultObj.hasOwnProperty(nameElement)
            ? levelResultObj[nameElement]
            : undefined; // eslint-disable-line no-undefined
    }, contentObj);
    return (resultVariable !== undefined) ? resultVariable : defaultReturn;
}
```

With this function you can get data from "deep objects" without having to check every level one by one. If any level fails you can give a return value as the third parameter. Something like this.

```
ObjectUtil.getVariable(this, 'props.recipe.ingredients', []);
```

This will return an empty array even if any level is undefined. Then you can call map without worries an either check its length or render the result it will contain nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some kinds of reasons.
At first `this.props.ingredients` would be not defined.
So to check the validation of `this.props.ingredients` yourself like this.

`const {recipe}= this.props;
console.log(recipe.ingredients);`

And then you may fix your issues by adding `if statement`

eg.

```
let ingredients;
if(recipe.ingredients !== undefined && ricipe.ingredients.length > 0)
{
    ingredients = recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => {
        console.log(ingredient);
        return <li key={recipeId}> {ingredient} </li>     
    })
}
else
    ingredient = null;
```